# In which ordered fields does absolute convergence imply convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ordered-fields

In the process of touching up some notes on infinite series, I came across the following "result":

> Theorem: For an ordered field $(F,<)$, the following are equivalent:
> (i) Every Cauchy sequence in $F$ is convergent.
> (ii) Absolutely convergent series converge: $\sum_n |a_n|$ converges in $F$  $\implies$ $\sum_n a_n$ converges in $F$.

But at present only the proof of (i) $\implies$ (ii) is included, and unfortunately I can no longer remember what I had in mind for the converse direction.  After thinking it over for a bit, I wonder if I was confusing it with this result:

> Proposition: In a normed abelian group $(A,+,|\cdot|)$, the following are equivalent:
> (i) Every Cauchy sequence is convergent.
> (ii) Absolutely convergent series converge: $\sum_n |a_n|$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$  $\implies$ $\sum_n a_n$ converges in $A$.

For instance, one can use a telescoping sum argument, as is done in the case of normed linear spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ in (VIII) of [this note](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Cohen77.pdf).

But the desired result is not a special case of this, because by definition the norm on a normed abelian group takes values in $\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$, whereas the absolute value on an ordered field $F$ takes values in $F^{\geq 0}$.

I can show (ii) $\implies$ (i) of the Theorem for ordered subfields of $\mathbb{R}$.  Namely, every real number $\alpha$ admits a *signed binary expansion* $\alpha = \sum_{n = N_0}^{\infty} \frac{\epsilon_n}{2^n}$, with $N_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\epsilon_n \in \{ \pm 1\}$, and the associated "absolute series" is $\sum_{n=N_0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} = 2^{1-N_0}$.

Because an ordered field is isomorphic to an ordered subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ iff it is Archimedean, this actually proves (ii) $\implies$ (i) for Archimedean ordered fields.  But on the one hand I would prefer a proof of this that does not use the (nontrivial) result of the previous sentence, and on the other hand...what about non-Archimedean ordered fields?

**Added**: The article based on this question and answer has at last appeared:

> Clark, Pete L.; Diepeveen, Niels J.;
> Absolute Convergence in Ordered Fields.
> Amer. Math. Monthly 121 (2014), no. 10, 909–916.

If you are a member of the MAA, you will be frustrated if you try to access it directly: the issue is currently advertised on their website but the articles are not actually available to members.  The article is available [on JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.121.10.909) and through MathSciNet.  Anyway, [here is an isomorphic copy](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Clark-Diepeveen14.pdf).  Thanks again to Niels Diepeveen!

Comment: Hah! I saw that this question has not been answered this morning, and was just about to add a bounty to it myself. (How many experts on non-Archimedean ordered fields do you think there are on Math.SE?)

Comment: @Willie: well, as I understand it (i.e., not very well), you are still free to tack on your own bounty.  As for your question...well, I am hoping for at least one.

Comment: I think only one bounty can be active on one question at a time. So if you still don't have an answer after the week, I'll put one on then.

Comment: If my answer is correct, you needed only a little more patience. It was nearly done yesterday.

Comment: In the most familiar non-Archimedean ordered field, convergence in the sense that is usual in real analysis is rarely if ever thought about at all.  The set of finite natural numbers is, after all, an external set.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark : That's not the one I had in mind when I referred to "the most familiar non-Archimedean ordered field".  I meant the nonstandard reals.  Otherwise I wouldn't have referred to the idea of an external set.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark : What sorts of topics are you working on in which that "comes up all the time"?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark : I think maybe the fact that the nonstandard reals are a non-Archimedean ordered field is more widely known than is the fact that the rationals functions are.  I don't think it's usually mentioned in high school.  What is it that you do with generating functions that involves convergence of sequences?

Comment: Certainly I've encountered ordered fields, and the fact that the rational functions form an ordered field, and that it's non-Archimedean.  Everybody knows they form a field.  That's it ordered, and non-Archimdean, are things that I thought were less widely known.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark : Certainly the field of ratioanl functions is simpler, but my impression had been that the fact that it's an _ordered_ field was not that widely known.

Comment: The last link is broken for me, but I found a pdf from your website: http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/Clark-Diepeveen14.pdf. May I edit it in?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Proving this for arbitrary ordered fields is a little
trickier than for Archimedean fields, partly because
there are no concrete sequences -- other than eventually
constant ones -- that are guaranteed to converge or
even to be Cauchy sequences and partly because we lack
the embedding in a completely ordered field.

These problems can be overcome by constructing all the
necessary sequences and series from the one Cauchy
sequence we assume to exist. To begin with, note two
important facts. First, for a Cauchy sequence to
converge, it is sufficient that some subsequence
converges. Second, any sequence has a strictly increasing
subsequence, a strictly decreasing subsequence or a
constant subsequence. For this problem, the latter
case is trivial and the first two can be reduced to each
other by negation, so we need to prove only one of them.

Let $K$ be an ordered field in which every absolutely
convergent series is convergent. If $\{a_n\}$ is a strictly
increasing Cauchy sequence in $K$, then $\{a_n\}$ converges.

**Proof:**

Let $b_n = a_{n+1} - a_n$. Then ${b_n}$ is positive and
converges to $0$, so it has a strictly decreasing
subsequence $\{b_{n_k}\}$.
Let $c_k = b_{n_k} - b_{n_{k+1}}$. We now have a convergent
series with positive terms $\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k = b_{n_1}$.
As $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, it has a subsequence $\{a_{m_k}\}$
such that $a_{m_{k+1}} - a_{m_k} < c_k$ for all $k$.

Now consider the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty d_i$ where
$d_{2k-1} = a_{m_{k+1}} - a_{m_k}$ and
$d_{2k} = a_{m_{k+1}} - a_{m_k} - c_k$.
Note that $-c_k < d_{2k} < 0 < d_{2k-1} < c_k$, so we can pair off
terms to get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty |d_i| = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (d_{2k-1} - d_{2k})
  = \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k = b_{n_1}
$$
By the hypothesis on $K$ we may conclude that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty d_i$
converges and
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty d_i + \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k
  = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (d_{2k-1} + d_{2k} + c_k)
  = 2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_{m_{k+1}} - a_{m_k}).
$$
Because a Cauchy sequence with a convergent subsequence converges,
we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a_{m_1} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_{m_{k+1}} - a_{m_k})
  = a_{m_1} + \frac{1}{2}\left(b_{n_1} + \sum_{i=1}^\infty d_i \right)
$$

---

To the question "how did I come up with this?": there are
not many things that could possibly work. The problem is
set in an environment where none of the power tools of
analysis work. Basic arithmetic works, inequalities work,
some elementary properties of sequences and series work, but
if you want to take a limit of something it'd better be
convergent by hypothesis or by construction.

One more or less obvious attack is by contraposition: assume
that there is a divergent Cauchy sequence and try to construct
a divergent, absolutely convergent series. Such a series
must be decomposable into a positive part $a$ and a negative
part $b$, where $a+b$ diverges and $a-b$ converges. This
is possible in several ways by taking $a$ and $b$ to be linear
combinations of known convergent and divergent series.

A complication is that the terms of the convergent series
must dominate those of the divergent series, as they must
control the signs. I wasted a lot of time trying to get the
convergent series to do this, which is very hard, perhaps
impossible. Then I turned to the proof for vector spaces
for inspiration, and saw that it was in fact very easy to
adjust the divergent series instead, as the partial sums
are a Cauchy sequence. I also adopted the
overall structure of that proof, which is why the final
version is not by contraposition.

Comment: This is fantastic!  I just read it over in some detail and it looks completely correct.  Because of my unfamiliarity with bounties I will wait a little while before formally accepting it to allow others a chance to vet the answer.  But I am very pleased with this.  May I include this argument in my notes http://math.uga.edu/~pete/3100supp.pdf?  I will attribute it to you.

Comment: By the way, there is some seriously clever stuff going on here: how did you come up with this?

Comment: +1, very nice. The key is the construction of $d$ -- that would seem slightly less magical (to me) if you require $d_{2k}-d_{2k-1}=c_k$ and $d_{2k}+d_{2k-1}=a_{m_{k+1}}-a_{m_k}$, with solution $d_{2k}=\frac12(a_{m_{k+1}}-a_{m_k}+c_k)$ and $d_{2k-1}=\frac12(a_{m_{k+1}}-a_{m_k}-c_k)$; then $\sum_i|d_i|=\sum_kc_k$ and $\sum_i d_i=\sum_k(a_{m_{k+1}}-a_{m_k})$.

Comment: Wow! Beautiful argument. I hope you don't mind my using this construction in future classes I teach.

Comment: @Pete L. Clark, Willie Wong: If you have any use for it, I'll be honoured.

Comment: @Niels: cool.  I have added this argument to the file listed in my first comment above.  (This is sort of a "source book"  on sequences and series.  In other words, its intended audience is not the typical undergraduate learning this material for the first time, but instructors for such courses / more advanced students / mathematicians interested in deepening their knowledge of this very classical subject.) ...

Comment: ...I have also become interested in the following (vaguely reverse-mathematical) question: given a theorem in calculus, does it hold (i) in every ordered field? (ii) in every Cauchy complete ordered field?  (iii) in every Archimedean ordered field? (iv) in every Dedekind complete ordered field (i.e., only the real numbers), et cetera.  To see the sort of thing I have in mind, see http://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.5652.pdf, especially Theorem 3.11.  But the present characterization of Cauchy completeness is not mentioned in that paper, nor anywhere else in the literature that I have been able to find.

Comment: @Niels: please email me if you get this message.  It turns out that a note in the September 2012 issue of the College Math Journal ends by asking precisely the question that I asked and you answered here.  So I have prepared a followup note with you as a coauthor.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Even though I don't understand all of it, you always ask such interesting questions. I'd rather understand however what's going on here, can you point me to some references/literature to back-fill, I asked what I am asking rather awkwardly here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655307/saturation-complete-ordered-fields-and-model-theoretic-methods-in-relation-to?noredirect=1#comment1382165_655307