# Mean Value Theorem used to prove "global properties"?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question

This is a soft question:

I am puzzled by this statement on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem:

> The theorem is used to prove global statements about a function on an
>   interval starting from local hypotheses about derivatives at points of
>   the interval.

I was thinking shouldn't it be the other way around? I.e. Prove local statement from global hypothesis?

$f$ differentiable on $(a,b)$ seems like a global hypothesis, while $f'(c)$ is a particular point, so it is a local statement?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! (+1 for the same)

---

Wikipedia is correct here. And it will be best to explain this using an actual concrete example. Let $f$ be differentiable at $a$ and let $f'(a) > 0$. Using limit definition of derivative and taking $\epsilon = f'(a)/2$ we see that there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $$\left|\frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h} - f'(a)\right| < \frac{f'(a)}{2}$$ for all $h$ with $0 < |h| < \delta$. This means that $$\frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h} > \frac{f'(a)}{2} > 0$$ for all $h$ with $0 < |h| < \delta$. Therefore $f(a + h) - f(a)$ has same sign as that of $h$ for $0 < |h| < \delta$. Thus if $h > 0$ then $f(a + h) > f(a)$ and if $h < 0$ then $f(a + h) < f(a)$.

Therefore *there is a neighborhood $I = (a - \delta, a + \delta)$ of $a$ such that if $x \in I, x > a$ then $f(x) > f(a)$ and if $x \in I, x < a$ then $f(x) < f(a)$.* If a function $f$ has such a behavior in some neighborhood of $a$ then we say that *$f$ is strictly increasing at point $a$.* The property of *strictly increasing at a point* is a local property and we have proved that:

*If $f'(a) > 0$ then $f$ is strictly increasing at $a$.*

Contrast this definition of local property of increasing at point with the global property of increasing on an interval. *A function $f$ defined on an interval $I$ is said to be strictly increasing on $I$ if $x, y \in I, x < y$ implies $f(x) < f(y)$.* Now it appears obvious that *if a function $f$ is strictly increasing at every point of an interval $I$ then it must be strictly increasing on $I$*. This fact is true but the proof is not trivial and requires us to use completeness property of real numbers.

However if we assume $f$ to be differentiable on $I$ then we can prove the following theorem:

*If $f$ is differentiable on $I$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in I$ then $f$ is strictly increasing on $I$.*

Proof is immediate from mean value theorem because $$f(x) - f(y) = f'(c)(x - y)$$ so that $f(x) - f(y)$ has same sign as that of $x - y$. Note that a positive derivative at each point implies that $f$ is strictly increasing at each point and using mean value theorem we have proved that $f$ is strictly increasing on $I$.

The above theorem is thus an example of deducing global property from a local one. Also note that the above theorem is a special case of the general theorem we discussed earlier which says that *a function which is strictly increasing at each point of an interval is strictly increasing on that interval irrespective of the fact whether the function is differentiable or not.*

---

The above demonstration also shows that mean value theorem is a very powerful one and should not be considered obvious or trivial. And like most [non-trivial theorems of calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1787254/72031) its proof also requires the completeness property of real numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed this satisfied my curiosity and showed the power of MVT.