# Prove that any upper bounded set have a supremum

Tags: real-analysis

> Using **Dedekind's theorem** and the property of real numbers, prove that if a set S is bounded above, then it has a supremum.

I just started real analysis and I thought this is so "trivial". But when I actually approach the problem, it feels difficult. Here is my proof (not sure if it's correct):

Consider a set $T=\{x \mid \exists y\in S\;$ such that $\;x\le y \}$, and $U=\{x \mid x\in \Bbb R\;x\notin T\}$ then using dedekind's theorem, there exists a real number $k$ such that every integer in $T$ is $\le k$ and every integer in $U$ is $\ge k$. Therefore the supremum is $k$.

Is this correct? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your proof is OK, but some typos. Replace integer with "real number". And further you might want to show that $T, U$ have the properties for which Dedekind theorem can be applied.

Comment: And once you are armed with [Dedekind theorem or its equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1787254/72031) most of the elementary real analysis proofs are trivial.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thank you :)

Comment: You may visit the link in previous comment to see Dedekind theorem equivalents.